Issue with colorspace Package when Loading ggplot2 in tidyverse using renv
I have used tidyverse and renv together for a long time, but recently I started getting an error I have been unable to resolve. The error suggest that colorspace package is failing in some way when loading ggplot2. I have un-installed and re-installed colorspace, tisyverse, and renv. And I still get the same error:
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL ‘colorspace’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.3.1 
2: In loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  package ‘colorspace’ has no 'package.rds' in Meta/
3: S3 methods ‘plot.hcl_palettes’, ‘print.hcl_palettes’, ‘summary.hcl_palettes’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 

Here is the output of sessionInfo():
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: America/Bogota
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.3.0    R6_2.5.1          magrittr_2.0.3    cli_3.6.1        
 [5] tools_4.3.0       tidyverse_2.0.0   glue_1.6.2        gtable_0.3.4     
 [9] rstudioapi_0.15.0 grid_4.3.0        lifecycle_1.0.4   rlang_1.1.2      
[13] renv_1.0.3       

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue.
I tried re-installing all the packages and asking ChatGPT, I was expecting that once I reinstalled the packages I would be able to use renv and tidyverse at the same time.
